# Upload Video To Facebook Page give an FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I uploaded video to facebook account main timeline successfully but when I am trying to upload video to facebook page using facebook Graph API (page access token)
from android native application. (use Facebook SDK 3.0.1 version )
But Video can't upload and recevied an error  :

```
**Graph URL** = https://graph-video.facebook.com/my_page_id/videos

params.putByteArray("source", byteArray);
params.putString("title", file.getName());
params.putString("description", getComment());
params.putString("access_token", getPageAccessToken());

**Request request = new Request(session, graphPath, params, HttpMethod.POST);**

{Request:  session: {Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[publish_actions, video_upload, user_videos, publish_stream, manage_pages]}, appId: **my_app_id** }, graphPath: **https://graph-video.facebook.com/my_page_id/videos**, graphObject: null, restMethod: null, httpMethod: POST, parameters: Bundle[{source=[B@42cfd058, description=desc_Details, **access_token=page_access_token**, migration_bundle=fbsdk:20121026}]}


Get and facebook response :

{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":false}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

I can't find what's going to be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have no permissions to do it. Check on your facebook app permissions